# Cant connect to my SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a php login form and every time i try to login it says "The username you entered was not found." witch i have in one of my if statement's in my code and i think its because I'm not linking something right to mySQL. I've been working on this for a couple of days now and cant fix it! can you guys help me please. thanks -John

```
<?
    $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login' /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>";

    if ($_POST['loginbtn']){
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($user){
            if ($password){
                require("connect.php");

                $password = md5(md5("ak3sfx".$password."58ghy7"));

                //Make sure login info is good
                $query = mysql_select_db("users");

                if ($numrows == 1){
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                    $dbuser = $row['users'];
                    $dbpassword = $row['password'];

                    if ($password == $dbpassword){
                        //Set session info
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusers;

                        echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b> <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to continue";

                    }
                    else
                        echo "You did not enter the right password. $form";

                }
                else
                    echo "The username you entered was not found. $form";

                mysql_close();

            }
            else
                echo"You must enter your password. $form";
        }
        else
            echo"You must enter your username. $form";
    }
    else
        echo $form;

?>
```

Comment: It is because the condition for `$numrows == 1` returns FALSE.  Where does `$numrows` came from?

Comment: Hey Logan, not really sure im just trying to go off memory. should i just take it out?

Comment: No. I assume that `$numrows` came from getting the number of result of rows from your table in a query somewhere.

Comment: Complete your given code.

Comment: should I keep going?? but it doesn't let me login it just says "The username you entered was not found" is that because its not connect to the database or mySQL?  ( database name: usersink table name: users ) then the column is named user

Comment: You should assign a valid value in your `$numrows`. Find where you establish this variable and update your post.

Comment: I thought `$numrows == 1` was a valid value, sorry ahead of time i dont really get what your asking me todo.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_select_db("users") will change db to users. Are you trying to select data from users table? If so, you need to change this line.

Have a look of this link. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
These example will help you

Comment: Hey Ivan, Im reading the link you posted but im not really sure what i should replace it with  |  mysql_fetch_assoc("users");

Comment: Maybe you can do some thing like this: $sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus
        FROM   sometable
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

Comment: I put the code in but it keeps breaking everything, im putting something in wrong but not sure what....